# InDesign interactive PDF scale slider options?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

Is there a way to create a scale slider(button as an interactive PDF within inDesign.

I know about the general buttons, radios, and text fields but can't seem to find anything on creating a scale to help gauge from like 1-10. Any help would be appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This widget does not exist as such in PDF.

You can create something comparable with a button field and an accordingly crafted icon and some logic. Instead of dragging, you would have to click on the location where it should appear.

It does require some understanding of PDF forms and Acrobat JavaScript, but it is feasible…

Comment: Thank you for responding. I just needed to make sure I wasn't over-looking the solution to the problem, since I don't use inDesign a lot for this purpose. Guess I will have to do some coding.